# java packages and "sub packges" - clarifaction please

Tags: java, package

I am asking for definate clarifaction regarding packages and sub directories within package directories.

A scenario  - say I have directory food that contains a sub directory fruit which I am using for package names.

I have a java file called apple.java and that contains a package statement :

package food.fruit;

I also have a java file called cheese.java and that has a package statement :

package food;

are package food and package food.fruit considered two completely seperate packages (say as distinct as package animal.dog and package flower.daisy ) or is package food.fruit considered a "sub package" of food package and has some kind relationship that could effect access in anyway? For example such as class files in the food package being able to call non public methods in food.fruit package?

From my research it seems that they would be considered completely seperate and do not have an inherited values.

Could someone please confirm if this is correct ?

What would be the reasons for using sub directory structures in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no package hierarchy in Java. There are no 'sub packages'. The `food` package and the `food.fruit` package are completely separate. This means that package-local things in the `food.fruit` package will not be accessible to anything in the `food` package or vice-versa.

The reason for subdirectories to exist is only semantic: They help group code together, and it makes it easy for someone to incorporate a directory of code in their project (rather than multiple directories).